# Why shouldn't we put business logic in services? Will we ever replace our services?

Tags: c#, java, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am designing a system and I have read many articles saying don't put business logic in your service code.  And only put your business logic in your domain objects.

I am not hosting my service code anywhere and it is directly accessed by my presentation layer.  In future, I might want to expose this service code via WCF IIS service.

But I don't understand why services should be light-weight?
What is the advantage of it?  When will we ever replace our services?  Please explain

Comment: Can you point to one of the articles you've read? And what do you mean by the term "service"? Having switched from Java to .NET recently, it seems to me that what's called the "service layer" in javaland would be called the "BLL layer" in dotnetland. In which case you're probably doing the right thing, and there's just a terminology confusion. If what you're doing is writing *web services* (using the WCF annotations), but not exposing them to the web but calling them directly, then your code organisation would be weird.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that by having different layers in your application, it makes it reusable. For example, your Business layer may have a function to check out a book. Well you can take that function and have it be called from different layers. A Console app can call it, a service can call it, or a web page can call it.

Additionally, it is easier to test. You can trigger the method in a sample application that just calls your BLL, and you don't have to worry about having your service call it.

Comment: console app will use domain logic code via service layer, web page will use service layer to get to domain logic, another service will call the service to access domain object then when am i ever replacing a service? if i am never replacing a service and you dont have a reason to give me when we will replace a service then whats the point of making service layer light?

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, this is about adherence to the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). The general idea is that the single responsibility of your service layer should be the translation of service operations to domain operations. I.e. you write a service type which exposes a method representing a service operation with a service contract as an input. The service method translates the service operation to a domain operation, and lets the domain object(s) worry about the business rules. This way your type encapsulates the translation of service operation to domain operation and nothing else.

Note that I am assuming that 'service' code, in the articles you are referring to, refers to the service interface in a [service oriented architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture).